# check if a record field contains a value using standard sql (Google BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For example, if I have a schema like this:

```
[{
    "name": "fullName",
    "type": "string",
    "mode": "required"
 },
 {
    "name": "children",
    "type": "record",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "fields": [
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string",
        "mode": "nullable"
    },
    {
        "name": "gender",
        "type": "string",
        "mode": "nullable"
    },
    {
        "name": "age",
        "type": "integer",
        "mode": "nullable"
    }] 
}]
```

where a person can have multiple children and children are stored in a repeated record and can be accessed with children.name, children.gender, and children.age.
There might be multiple rows displayed for this person if this person has more than one child, but all of these rows shares one row number.

I would like to select all rows from this table where one of the child's name in a row matches a certain value, I am thinking it might be something like children.name contains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I read your question as - How to select all parents who have child with specific name?

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE 'child1' IN (SELECT name FROM UNNEST(children))
```

You can test above with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 
    'parentA' AS fullName, 
    [STRUCT<name STRING, gender STRING, age INT64>
      ('child1', 'm', 10), ('child2', 'f', 11), ('child3', 'f', 8)
    ] AS children UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parentB', 
    [STRUCT<name STRING, gender STRING, age INT64>
      ('child4', 'm', 10), ('child5', 'f', 11), ('child6', 'f', 8)] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parentC', 
    [STRUCT<name STRING, gender STRING, age INT64>
      ('child7', 'm', 10), ('child1', 'f', 11), ('child8', 'f', 8)] 
)
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE 'child1' IN (SELECT name FROM UNNEST(children))
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to any name from a given list? Like ['child1', 'child2']?