# How to filter structs with some key in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There is data like this:

```
Date, struct.key: struct.value
2019, {1: 'nice', 2: 'nice', 3: 'not nice'}
2020, {2: 'nice', 3: 'not nice'}
```

How to filter all structs in which a key=1 appears?

Expected output:

```
Date, struct.key: struct.value
2019, {1: 'nice', 2: 'nice', 3: 'not nice'}
```

Comment: select * from table where struct.key like '%1:%' - awful data model though..

Comment: What is the data type of `struct`?

Comment: The data type is {string: string, ...}, but I'm looking for an universal solution.

Comment: example of input data and expected result will help us to help you! if the input data example you already have in question - the best you can do - at least show the expected output based on that example.

Comment: I finally found something that works here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004592/check-if-a-record-field-contains-a-value-using-standard-sql-google-bigquery. So probably this is a duplicate.

Comment: @bry888 - if you found something that was useful for you - consider voting up the answers you found useful!

Answer (score 0):

By having:

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2019 AS date, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(key, value))
  FROM (SELECT "1" as key,"nice" as value UNION ALL
  SELECT "2" as key,"nice" as value UNION ALL
  SELECT "3" as key,"not nice" as value)) AS structcolumn
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2020 AS date, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(key, value))
  FROM (SELECT "2" as key,"nice" as value UNION ALL
  SELECT "3" as key,"not nice")) AS structcolumn
)
SELECT 
  date,key,value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,UNNEST(structcolumn) AS STRUCTCOL
WHERE STRUCTCOL.key="1"
```

The output is the following:

[image: Results]

Hope it helps.